# Python debugger for bazel targets in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, bazel

I am studying a repository and for that I am running bazel targets that require command line arguments. I want to debug the code in Pycharm, using the Pycharm debugger(I don't want to use pdb). The repository is structured in a way that when I run the code using the Pycharm debugger, I get import errors, and I can only run it as a bazel target from terminal using `bazel run <path to file> -- arguments`.
I want to run it in such a way that I can load all the variables similar to the image - [Pycharm console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApMmx.png)

Comment: Issue is being discussed here -> https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/2093